# GUI tool to extract iso file contents on Linux (KDE)

Tags: linux, kde, gui, iso-image, extract

I have an ISO CD image file and want to extract it's contents to a folder.
I know there are ways to mount the image and stuff, but it's complicated.

I'm looking for a GUI tool to open up the contets and extract needed files.
On windows I would use WinRar to do this. 
K3B only allows me to burn the stuff, Arch does not work with ISO files :(

Is there a similar tool on Linux, preferably from KDE world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gnome File Roller did the job perfectly. 
Too bad Ark (KDE compress/decompress tool) has no ISO support.

Answer (score 4):

[**AcetoneISO**](http://www.acetoneteam.org/) will let you extract ISO contents and works under GNOME and KDE.

[image]

It requires kommander to be installed. Full install directions can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/extract-convert-mount-iso-bin-daa-nrg.html).

Comment: Voted up for best answer. Similar but inferior programs: kiso, ISOmorphin, isomaster, furiusisomount and, as KIO slave, kio_iso

Answer (score 3):

I believe mounting the iso is the best way to go, mount it and copy the files that you want, the command is:

```
mount -o loop disk1.iso /mnt/disk
```

keep in mind that you can create a shortcut, scripts or even a shell extension (right click menu) to run the above command for you.

Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Try "isomaster". I use it in Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

I used ArchLinux with kde complete DE and as I can remember it would be enough to click on the iso image to get it auto-mounted: am I wrong?

Comment: Not working here on Arch + KDE 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Under Fedora and Gnome i done in once with gvfs. gvfs-archive must do it. may be gvfs-fuse +fuse-iso